# Is the converse of Euler's Theorem on Homogeneous Functions true?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable. Prove that, if $f$ is homgeneous of degree $k$, then:

$\sum_{i=1}^n$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}x_i$ $= kf$

I have been able to prove this. I was just curious, is the converse true? I've been told it can be found in many calculus books but it is actually false.

Comment: The converse holds: [look here](http://planetmath.org/converseofeulershomogeneousfunctiontheorem).

Comment: The converse only holds for *positively* homogenous functions. Many textbooks define homogenous to mean positively homogenous. The converse does not necessarily hold otherwise.